# For-Loop to Generate Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array

thank you in advance for taking the time to help me with this question.

I am trying to generate a simple board like so, using a for loop.

```
var board = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
```

However, my attempt below has not been successful.

```
function makeBoard(n){
  var board=[];
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<n; j++){
      board[i][j]=0;
    }
  }
  return board;
}
```

Technically, I could just use the board variable I have shown above, and continue, but I am more concerned with the principle. Is it not possible to create a multidimensional array using for loop? Is there a simple way to accomplish this using array.push()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have multidimensional arrays, so you have to use an array of arrays instead:

```
function makeBoard(n){
  var board=[];
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    board[i] = [];
    for(var j=0; j<n; j++){
      board[i][j]=0;
    }
  }
  return board;
}
```

You were missing the `board[i] = [];` needed to create each array for the second dimension.

Note: You could also use [Array.prototype.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

```
function makeBoard(n){
  var board=[];
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    board[i] = Array(n).fill( 0 );
  }
  return board;
}
```

Comment: fill works only on [selected user agents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @isvforall That doesn't work, since `Array.fill` doesn't do a deep copy. You end up with `board[0] === board[1] === board[2] ...` all references to the same array

Answer (score 1):

You need for every new sub array an initialisation as [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```js
function makeBoard(n){
    var board=[];
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        board[i] = []; // <-- this is missing!
        for(var j=0; j<n; j++){
            board[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    return board;
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(makeBoard(5), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Another version without for loop

```js
function makeBoard(n){
    return Array.apply(null, {length: n}).map(function () {
        return Array.apply(null, {length: n}).map(function () {
            return 0;
        });
    });
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(makeBoard(5), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You generate an array and then loop new arrays inside of that. Something like this:

```
var arr = new Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr[i] = new Array(6);
}
```